# SQL join uniquely

Tags: sql, join, uniq

I have two tables and I want to join them with subqueries. I know that we can do it an easier way, but they want me to do it like this. But my code is not working, and I could no find a way to fix it.

This is my code - can someone tell me what is wrong with it?

```
select distinct 
    c.region,
    c.data_center,
    c.suite,
    c.pr_date,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(m.siteops_exit_actual) as LROOF
from
    (select 
         region, data_center, suite, pr_date 
     from  
         IDC_DC_SCHED_DATES_SUITES_DEV_FUTURE 
     where  
         ds = '<LATEST_DS:IDC_DC_SCHED_DATES_SUITES_DEV_FUTURE>') c
left outer join
    (select 
         region, datacenter, suite, max(siteops_exit_actual) 
     from 
         suplan_migrations:cea 
     where 
         ds = '<LATEST_DS:suplan_turnups:cea>' 
     group by 
         region, datacenter, suite) m on c.region = m.region 
                                      and c.data_center = m.datacenter 
                                      and c.suite = m.suite
```

Comment: What error are you getting.  What database are you using?

Comment: it says m.siteops_exit_actual can not be found. do you see any syntax error in this code?

Comment: Clarify via edits, not comments. [mre]

Answer (score 1):

You need to *name* the aggregation column in the subquery:

```
select distinct c.region, c.data_center, c.suite, c.pr_date,
      FROM_UNIXTIME(m.siteops_exit_actual) as LROOF
from IDC_DC_SCHED_DATES_SUITES_DEV_FUTURE c left join
     (select region, datacenter,suite, max(siteops_exit_actual) as siteops_exit_actual
      from `suplan_migrations:cea`
      where ds = '<LATEST_DS:suplan_turnups:cea>' 
      group by region, datacenter, suite
     ) m 
     on c.region = m.region and c.data_center = m.datacenter and c.suite = m.suite
where c.ds = '<LATEST_DS:IDC_DC_SCHED_DATES_SUITES_DEV_FUTURE>');
```

I removed the first subquery as well.

Comment: can I keep the format, having two defined table in select statement, like I have it. I don't get it why that one is not working. since I have a table defined in both select statements

Comment: @RaminRafat . . . Your code looks like MySQL code.  Unnecessary subqueries in the `FROM` clause can prevent the optimizer from doing some optimizations.  I don't recommend that.